# CocoaPods update. Terminal shows previous version

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, rubygems, cocoapods

I tried to update cocoapods gem with command `sudo gem install cocoapods`. After few minutes on installation I saw `Successfully installed cocoapods-0.29.0`. But when I type `pod --version` got `0.27.1` again. Moreover when I try `pod install` terminal shows me this error:

```
[!] Pod::Executable pull

A   ALPValidator/0.0.1/ALPValidator.podspec

A   Apptimize/1.5.8/Apptimize.podspec

A   BloodMagic/0.5.2/BloodMagic.podspec

U   CardIO/3.2.2/CardIO.podspec

U   CardIO/3.3.0/CardIO.podspec

U   CardIO/3.4.0/CardIO.podspec

U   CardIO/3.4.3/CardIO.podspec

...
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On January 28 the Cocoapods Specs repo broke -- [here](http://blog.cocoapods.org/Repairing-Our-Broken-Specs-Repository/)'s the full explanation and fix:

Answer (score 1):

A bug was found in libgit2 and they had to execute a force push on the specs repo in order to fix the issue. This is what broke everyone CocoaPods setup.

You can find the details on what to do [here](http://blog.cocoapods.org/Repairing-Our-Broken-Specs-Repository).

Meanwhile you can use this quick fix :

```
rm -rf ~/.cocoapods/
pod setup
```